# Download File after submission in Contact Form 7 Wordpress (deprecated on_sent_ok)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, deprecated, contact-form-7, dom-events

I want the user to download a PDF file after submitting a simple Contact Form 7 in Wordpress.

I see that the on_sent_ok is deprecated and won't be allowed by the end of 2017 and should be replaced by DOM Events.

I am having issues achieving this with the following code:

.htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

functions.php:

```
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   if ( '1497' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
      location( 'http://stagingarea2.craigsapsford.com/wpcontent/uploads/dlm_uploads/2017/11/Test-Document.pdf' );
   }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Where am i going wrong with this current setup?

Comment: add an `alert` before the if to check if the code reaches it. If the URL is changing but you get the 404 error, check the pdf url. I recommend you to upload it on the media and set the given URL.

Comment: Hi @Maxwells.c, I added the `alert` and it reached the browser. I have uploaded the PDF to Media and updated the URL in the functions.php. The form sends ok but I don't get the download. I'm not getting a 404 error. I stay on the same page, get the thank you message attached with the form but no PDF download.

Comment: try to use `window.open` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp (and check if you are downloading the file without notice...)

Comment: would the `window.open` replace the `location` in the functions.php code? I tried this but it didn't change anything.

Comment: window.open will open an popup. Try to make the alert **inside** the if statement. Maybe it isn't reaching.

Comment: I have added the window.open before the closed if statement bracket with no luck.

Comment: so this conditional `'1497' == event.detail.contactFormId` is giving false. Debug `event.detail` logging it and check what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy, paste and edit this in your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
if ( 'FORM ID' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = 'FILE PATH';
}
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

After the above, paste the following into your .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

This worked for me. Cheers